# rephrase the if statement in Dart 2.0 using null

Tags: flutter, dart

I have following statement in flutter. `weight` is the text from _weightController i.e. `_weightController.text`

```
int.parse(weight).toString().isNotEmpty && int.parse(weight) > 0
```

But in Dart 2.0 it is not working properly. For empty TextField, it is giving the error.

```
====== Exception caught by gesture ==============================
The following FormatException was thrown while handling a gesture: 
Invalid number (at character 1)
```

The code block is like this.

```
if (int.parse(weight).toString().isNotEmpty && int.parse(weight) > 0)
    return int.parse(weight) * multiplier;
  else
    print('Error');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to the other answer, you can use the [tryParse() method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int/tryParse.html):

> Like parse except that this function returns null where a similar call to parse would throw a FormatException, and the source must still not be null.

If you use this approach, you should check the return value for null:

```
String weight ="";
int number = int.tryParse(weight);
if (number !=null){
  print(number );
}
else
  print("error");
```

Don't forget to also check the variable for null with `weight ? ""` or with `weight != null`

Comment: This worked for me. `if (int.tryParse(weight) != null && int.tryParse(weight) > 0)`. Thanks. I also need to check for 0.

Comment: You mean weight ?? " ", Not single ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (weight != null && weight.isNotEmpty) {
  return int.tryParse(weight) * multiplier;
} else {
  print("CoolTag: error");
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: This worked partially though. I had to also check for 0 which was giving error. I used `int.tryParse(weight) > 0` and that worked for me.

Comment: Ok, but the accepted answer doesn't cover all the cases, which mine does.